# White space below footer

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta, footer

I just noticed that here on meta the footer doesn't stick to the bottom of the page, I know that it's not that big of a deal but it does look a bit clumsy.

[image]

Shouldn't there be an easy fix for this?

**EDIT:**

Since this has been reproduced and discussed by some members I was wondering if anyone is actually trying to fix this?

**EDIT:** (imported from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244444/202832), [before an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/244444/1))

`#footer.categories #svnrev` has `margin-bottom: 10px;`. It should have `margin:0`, or be moved alongside `#copyright`.

Comment: Repro-ed in IE11/FF and Chrome.

Comment: It's the revision number fault, for some reason its container got a `margin-bottom: 10px;` CSS rule causing this gap. (@Oded FYI as well :))

Comment: I wouldn't say that specific margin is to blame, @ShadowWizard. Specifying that should still make the wrapping divs grow  to allow for that margin?

Comment: @Arjan: `padding-bottom` would, margin is "outside" the element (I think, not good at CSS).

Comment: @Mat, that would apply to the outer divs. But what's "outside" some child div, is "inside" its parent div :-)

Comment: ...but maybe you're right: adding some padding to `<div class="footerwrap">` to increase its height and hence make some room for *the last* margin, fixes things. Hmmm, even only adding `padding-bottom: 1px` fixes it... Good luck investigating to all of you :-)

Comment: @Arjan using Chrome dev tools I removed the margin and the white space was gone.

Comment: Sure, @ShadowWizard, but that doesn't imply it's also the cause of it :-) (Like if you add a single pixel of padding to its parent "footerwrap", all is fixed too.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, `margin-bottom: 10px;` is on all the other SE sites, so I don't think its the cause of this.

Comment: @Bolu true, and the space is there on all other sites, but MSE is the only site where it's "disruptive".

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I didn't (and still can't) see the space on any other sites though....

Comment: @Bolu because it's not white, e.g. [Stack Overflow](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QcMsR.png), [Travel](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SkIAv.png). Both got a generic background color that fills the gap, while MSE is white.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, yeah, I've thought about that, but how about http://pets.stackexchange.com/ the background is based on [This picture?](http://cdn.sstatic.net/beta/img/bg-noise.png?v=57dc9ca1e3af)

Comment: We will get to it. But this is hardly a high priority bug/issue. What's the hurry?

Comment: @Oded I know it isn't something that has to be fixed right away and I understand that the priority is probably somewhere else but since there wasn't any "official" responce I was just wondering if it had even been noticed by a mod or something.

Comment: All questions with the [meta-tag:bug] tag are tracked by the team. We don't always feel the need to give an official response directly on the post. In particular something like this.

Comment: @Oded if not bumped, bugs can sit for long years - and visual bugs that affect all pages, well, might deserve bit more attention. :)

Comment: The difference is that MSE has `#footer { padding: 0; }` while e.g. SO has `#footer { padding: 15px; }`.