# Missing whitespace on tag wiki edit pages

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, meta

The text on tag wiki edit pages (Such as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/342)) is bumping into the header:

> [image: bug is buggy]

`#mainbar` currently has `margin: 0 10px 0 0`. It should have `margin: 10px 10px 0 0`.

---

I am using Chrome 39, but this issue should appear in any standards-compliant browser.

Comment: Happens on SeaMonkey 2.30 as well.  Which I am using to browse Meta today for some reason.

Comment: Footer bug already reported: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230683/white-space-below-footer

Comment: Cheers for the edit, was sure the missing space was also reported but couldn't find it. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I added info to the other post as well.